# Please Resolve this error

Tags: solidity, error, require

Why I am getting the error in the modifier function its showing red underline under the _amount variable name.

I also want to ask about whether the require function works inside the modifier because when I wrote my statement **"require(_checkOwner() || allowance[msg.sender] >_amount,"You are not allowed!");"** inside the modifier it showed me error. So now I am trying with defining the above require statement
inside a function and then calling it in modifier. Is this the correct way?? Also please answer about why I am getting error for _amount in the statement which is being called inside modifier function **"requiredCondition(uint _amount);".**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.16;
import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";

contract SharedWallet is Ownable{

    mapping(address => uint) public allowance;

    fallback () external payable{
        
    }
    
    receive () external payable {

    }

    modifier ownerOrAllowed(uint _amount) {
        requiredCondition(uint _amount);
        _;
    }

    function requiredCondition(uint _amount) public {
        require(_checkOwner() || allowance[msg.sender] >_amount,"You are not allowed!");
    }

    function addAllowance(address _who, uint _amount) public onlyOwner{
        allowance[_who] = _amount;
    }

    function withdrawMoney(address payable _to, uint _amount) public ownerOrAllowed(_amount){
        _to.transfer(_amount);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are (re)declaring a variable name that has already been used/declared as a parameter.
take out the second uint

```
modifier ownerOrAllowed(uint _amount) {
    requiredCondition(_amount);
    _;
}
```

also, _checkOwner() doesn't return bool. you can't use it like this. it just reverts if msg.sender isn't owner

Comment: Oh thank you but still it didn't reolve my error actually now it says that  from solidity:
TypeError: Operator || not compatible with types tuple() and bool.
  --> Project/SharedWallet.sol:23:17:
   |
23 |         require(_checkOwner() || allowance[msg.sender] >_amount,"You are not allowed!");
   |

Comment: _checkOwner() doesn't return bool. you can't use it like this. it just reverts if msg.sender isn't owner

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the error in the modifier function its showing red underline under the _amount variable name because you wrote the data type "uint" before "_amount". In addition, you are getting an error in your statement "require(_checkOwner() || allowance[msg.sender] >_amount,"You are not allowed!");" because the operator || is not compatible with types tuple() and bool.

Comment: So how should I correct this??